# VC++ 2010 can access class variable vector of struct from Main() but not from class function

Tags: visual-c++

I have written a header file with one basic data structure.

**ProdList.h**

```
#ifndef LISTOFITEMS_H
#define LISTOFITEMS_H


struct ListOfItems
{   
    public:
        std::string fdcustid;
        std::string fdstkid;
        std::string fdordisquantity;
        std::string fdordsstatus; // <> 'H'
        std::string fdordhtype; // <> 'A'
};


#endif /* GRANDFATHER_H */
```

now that I have a data structure I include it in the class definition and use the data structure "ListOfItems" in the class "ProdContainer".

**ProdContainer.h**

```
#include "ProdList.h"

class ProdContainer
{


public:
    ProdContainer(void);
    ~ProdContainer(void);
    static void SetNumberOfElements(int Elements);

    std::vector<ListOfItems> Items;
}
```

now when i write the following in Main.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ProdContainer myobject;
myobject.Items.resize(12);
printf("The size of Items is %i \n", myobject.Items.size());
return 0;
}
```

All goes as expected and I get the following output.

```
The size of Items is 12
```

Which is all fine and good. However, I want to encapsulate the data within the class and only allow access through class functions.
The problem arises when I add the following code to "SetNumberOfElements" implementation.

```
void ProdContainer::SetNumberOfElements(int Elements)
{
    Items.resize(Elements);
}
```

When I try to compile this "error C2228 left of '.resize' must have class/struct/union" appears and I am at a loss at what to do next.
I have searched high and low and cant seem to find any posts matching this particular problem, it's probably a schoolboy error. I've checked the MSDN site on error C2228 and as far as I can see Items is a substantiated variable of struct type ListOfItems, so I can't see why this error is appearing.
Is there a method for accessing a vector of a struct or some other aspect that I just can't see.
Please help, I am just about ready to explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access `static` data from `static` functions. So change this

```
static void SetNumberOfElements(int Elements);
```

To this

```
void SetNumberOfElements(int Elements);
```

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks so much for this. It is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access non-static class members from the static function.

What you can do is to "switch" from static to non-static.

```
static void SetNumberOfElements( void * lParam, int Elements)
{
     ((ProdContainer*)lParam)->Items.resize( Elements );
}
```

Use it like this inside your class:

```
SetNumberOfELements( this, 10 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Roger Rowland's answer may be more elegant for this particular; However, your suggestion would indeed work and has given me and idea for another feature I would like to add in the future as it allows the passing of a pointer to a substantiated variable. It is something I would not have considered myself, but now I know it's an option I will probably use it in future projects.